# How to make data display in the table on my webpage once it's been input into my database?

Tags: php, html

I'm not sure how to describe it, so here's a [video](https://youtu.be/mbdtZFMrrVk) where I explain my problem.

I tried rearranging some of the code, as I do believe nothing is faulty, attempting to make sure that the table refreshes with the new data inside it, however every time I tried to place my code in a different order (executing the queries in different orders), it either functions differently than how I want it to function or it doesn't function at all.

Both queries do function separately, I'm just unsure why they're not working together.

Searchbar has the value seen inputted in the homepage on both my Search page and this page in question. However it was left blank for this page, which gave me the result of having the full table display which is what I wanted to happen. I'm just not sure how I can edit my code so, when submitted, it will display the newly added data.

My PHP:

```php
<?php
$find     = $_POST['searchbar'];
$host     = "localhost";
$username = "FFF";
$pword    = "L3FhqJNey8Op2qJY";
$database = "Project";

include 'includes/db.inc.php';

$Name2          = $_POST['Name'];
$YearOfRelease2 = $_POST['YearOfRelease'];
$Studio2        = $_POST['Studio'];
$Age2           = $_POST['Age'];
$Score2         = $_POST['Score'];
?>
```

My HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Add a Film - Films! Films! FILMS!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Films! Films! FILMS!</h1>
        <h2>Add a Film</h2>
        <p>If you wish to add a film to our database, feel free to add data relating to the film in the respective boxes below. You should then refresh the page.</p>
        <p>Add Film:</p>
        <form method="POST" action="AddFilm.php">
        <p>Name of Film: <input type="text" name="Name"></p>
        <p>Year of Release: <input type="text" name="YearOfRelease"></p>
        <p>Name of Studio: <input type="text" name="Studio"></p>
        <p>Age Rating: <select name="Age" size="1">
            <optgroup label="Select Age Rating">
                <option value="U">U</option>
                <option value="PG">PG</option>
                <option value="12">12</option>
                <option value="15">15</option>
                <option value="18">18</option>
            </optgroup>
        </select></p>
        <p>Review Score: <input type="text" name="Score"></p>

        <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit and Refresh"></p>
        </form>
        <?php
        echo "<h2>$output</h2>";
        $query_string = "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE Name LIKE '%$find%' OR YearOfRelease LIKE '%$find%' OR Studio LIKE '%$find%' OR Age LIKE '%$find%' OR Score  LIKE '%$find%'";

        $query_string2 = "INSERT INTO movies (Name, YearOfRelease, Studio, Age, Score) VALUES ('$Name2', '$YearOfRelease2', '$Studio2', '$Age2', '$Score2');";

        if ($result = $mysqli->query($query_string2)) {
            $output2 = $Name2 ." has been added to the database.";
            echo "<p>$output2</p>";

            } else {
            echo ("Error performing query: " . $mysqli->error() );
        }
        $result->close();

        if ($result = $mysqli->query($query_string)) {
            echo "<table border='1'>";
            echo "<tr><th>FilmID</th><th>Name</th><th>YearOfRelease</th><th>Studio</th><th>Age</th><th>Score</th></tr>";

        while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
            {
                $FilmID = $row->FilmID;
                $Name = $row->Name;
                $YearOfRelease = $row->YearOfRelease;
                $Studio = $row->Studio;
                $Age = $row->Age;
                $Score = $row->Score;

                $output ="<tr><td> $FilmID";
                $output = $output . "<td> $Name";
                $output = $output . "<td> $YearOfRelease";
                $output = $output . "<td> $Studio";
                $output = $output . "<td> $Age";
                $output = $output . "<td> $Score </tr>";

                echo "<p>$output</p>";
            }
            echo "</table>";
            echo "<hr>";
            echo '<p><a href="Home.html">Back to Home Page</a></p>';
            $result->close();
        } else {
            echo ("Error performing query: " . $mysqli->error() );
        }

        $mysqli->close();
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I appreciate it may not always be easy to explain one’s problem, but don’t expect us to watch a video to understand this question.

Comment: why dont you use angular js to connect to your db? it's simple and will solve your problem

Comment: The reason why your table is not updated is because the `select` statement was executed before your `insert` statement. The `select` query simply ask the database to fetch the data from the database and back to your web in **THAT** moment and then stops. As you inserted your new data into the database after the `select` query, it will not be updated. Hope I'm clear.

Comment: @suppko unless something has changed that I can not see, the variable order does not execute the query statements, and the order of operations to select **after** the insert statement has been executed is correct. The issue would be that the select statement in the question has a criteria that may not match the insert. And unless `$_POST['searchbar']` is defined it would be null.

Comment: @MattMoir please update your question with how `$_POST['searchbar']` is defined. As that is the criteria set to your `SELECT` statement.

Comment: @Harshit it's for a school project and I'm not allowed to use javascript